# trying to add a new class error : import cannot be resolved

Tags: jsp, classpath, tomcat6

I am trying to add a new class to a pre-existing web application in Tomcat6.

The class is:

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
   System.out.println("HELLLLLLOOOOOOO");
  }
}
```

- I compiled it and put the class file in: `<WEBAPP>/WEB-INF/classes`
- Restart tomcat
  I called it from the jsp which works with other classes in folders in the classes directory:
  `<%@ page import="Hello" %>`

It fails saying:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 16 in the generated java file The import Hello cannot be resolved

What am I missing?

I have also tried adding it to the catalina common/lib directory, put it external to tomcat and edited the shared.loader property in catalina.properties.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: do you realize that just importing the class won't invoke its `main()` method? Also, I'd suggest to learn Servlets and Javabeans before it's [too late](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it in a package.

```
package com.example;
```

And put it in classpath accordingly:

```
/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/Hello.class
```

Finally import it as follows:

```
<%@ page import="com.example.Hello" %>
```

Packageless classes are invisible/unimportable for classes inside a package. The JSP file itself is namely implicitly been converted to a servlet class inside a servletcontainer-specific package.